# How can I read code from .py file as string in C#?

Tags: c#, python

I want to put some python script's into resources to not implement it in code like this:

```
Code = "if pos.IsConstruction: \r\n pos.Mirror()" // Code is string
```

So I made .resx file named _PythonScripts and put that code into .py file.
I was trying to read this like that example, but IDE is talking me that this is binary file.

```
Code = Resources._PythonScripts.clear
```

I can add that this is working on .sql files but on .py not.
Can You give me tip how Can I read this?

Comment: You could refer to the file itself in a .resx as a path, use the path to open the file in your code and parse the code inside the .py file. I've never done something like that but it should be possible, you should look for something like a Python Parser for C# because there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: How did you add the file? The extension of the *original* file doesn't matter - it's either a text file or not. The *IDE* doesn't have anything to do with how the code runs either. Do you get a compilation error? What exactly?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'. 
This is a .txt file with ranamed .txt to .py to easier write python scripts in VisualStudio

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is called `hello.py`, do

```
string hello = File.ReadAllText("hello.py")
```

see [File.ReadAllText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank You, but it gives the same result. Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'

Comment: @TheNa2rat no, `File.ReadAllText` returns a string, not `byte[]`, check the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Since python scripts are just text files, save a copy of the .py file as a .txt file and then import it into the resources file.